# Python post against API using date parameters for data?

Tags: python, json, parameters, python-requests

I can post JSON data using something like the following:

```
response = requests.post(url, auth=(username, password))
print(str(response.json()))
```

And I can see all the data.

However, the url in question reportedly points to data that has available parameters like this per documentation:

```
{
    "auditParameters": {
        "startDate": "Aug 29, 2023 12:00 AM",
        "endDate": "Aug 29, 2023 11:59 PM"
    }
}
```

I am unsure how to incorporate this so that only results from August 29 show up.  I have tried the following without success (it prints all data, not just the 29th):

```
headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8"}
params = {'auditParameters': {'startDate': 'Aug 29, 2023 12:00 AM', 'endDate': 'Aug 29, 2023 11:59 PM'}}
response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, params=params, auth=(username, password))
```

I've also tried to do the params like this:

```
params = {'startDate': 'Aug 29, 2023 12:00 AM', 'endDate': 'Aug 29, 2023 11:59 PM'}
```

I end up getting all the data, not just the data for the 29th.

I've checked with the organization responsible for the API the URL refers to, but they are unsure how to do that in Python. Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

When you're sending data in a POST request, you should generally use the data or json argument rather than params. The params argument is used to send data in the query string of a URL, typically for GET requests. But the JSON structure you provided indicates that the data is meant to be in the body of the request, which is typical for POST requests.

There are two ways to send the data:

```
import json

data = {
    "auditParameters": {
        "startDate": "Aug 29, 2023 12:00 AM",
        "endDate": "Aug 29, 2023 11:59 PM"
    }
}

response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(data), auth=(username, password))
print(str(response.json()))
```

Using json:

```
data = {
    "auditParameters": {
        "startDate": "Aug 29, 2023 12:00 AM",
        "endDate": "Aug 29, 2023 11:59 PM"
    }
}

response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=data, auth=(username, password))
print(str(response.json()))
```

Using the json argument automatically sets the "Content-Type" header to "application/json" and also serializes the Python object to JSON for you.

Comment: I get {'success': False, 'message': 'Aug 23, 2023 12:00 AM'}

Comment: Yet, the same credentials work when I just do response = requests.post(url, auth=(username, password)) though it yields not just the data from the 23rd, which I attempted for the parameters.